# Disable content bouncing scroll

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

In my `hybrid` app there's a possibility to drag the screen to refresh the list. In `Android` this works fine, but on `iOS` when I'm dragging down it sometimes confuses it with scrolling the page so it has that overflow/bouncing effect.

In `ionic` there's an attribute you can use to disable this, but it's not working:

```
<ion-content id="questions" has-bouncing="false">
```

config.xml already has these lines of code:

```
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to set `overflow-scroll` to `false` like :

`overflow-scroll="false"`

Works on **Ionic 1.3**

Comment: Do you have overflow-scroll="true" set somewhere ?

Comment: I don't, would it help if I add it and set it on false?

Comment: It did, by setting it on `false`

Comment: @Kapilsoni: inside <ion-content> tag

Comment: @radioaktiv sir its remove the bouncing effect in the normal page but not working in segment section and in the segment same bouncing problem sir?

Comment: @Kapilsoni What version of Ionic are you using ?

Comment: @radioaktiv i am using  ionic3.9.3 version?

Comment: @Kapilsoni My answer is regarding 1.3, sorry ;\

Answer (score 20):

Solution for Ionic 2:

```
<ion-content no-bounce>
```

Answer (score 6):

on ionic 4 `<ion-content no-bounce has-bouncing="false" forceOverscroll="false">`. If this fail force to remove bounce with.

To remove and force the not bounce in the component ion-content on ios, create the file DisableBounce.m
With the following content.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@implementation UIScrollView (NoBounce)
- (void)didMoveToWindow {
    [super didMoveToWindow];
    self.bounces = NO;
}
@end
```

and to save on platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Private/Plugins/CDVUIWebViewEngine.
this disable all efect bounce in you app.

Comment: worked for me in Ionic 4, this page already had a condition top of the page but, it was not fulfilling somehow, it should be work by adding in preferences but not working, this solution worked for me.

Comment: worked perfectly on ionic 3. I was trying to disable this bouncing effect on iOS for long. Thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

For Ionic 4, use:

```
<ion-content [scrollY]="false">...</ion-content>
```

Comment: this remove the scroll and no the bounce effect

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `ionic 1.3.2` and the following worked for me:

```
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

All this with `has-bouncing="false"` on each `ion-content`. I didn't make a thorough test to check the minimum requirements that will do the job. Yet the outcome: no bouncing in `iOS` and `android`.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

**Below solution worked for me : Tested only ionic 3.9 version**

Run command,

1. ionic cordova platform add ios && ionic cordova prepare ios
2. Then find CDVWKWebViewEngine.m, inside
   /platforms/ios//Plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/
3. Put this line of code at the bottom of the lines and save it.

```js
@implementation UIScrollView (NoBounce)
- (void)didMoveToWindow {
   [super didMoveToWindow];
   self.bounces = NO;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

`overflow-scroll="false"` nor `no-bounce` nor `has-bouncing="false"` has effect.. I was trying clean ionic project `ionic conference` and applied mentioned attributes to ion-content at speakers list page.. bouncing of scroll has not been disabled

cli packages: (/Users/lucky/Documents/projects/ionic-conference/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.3.1
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.1
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.1 
ios-sim    : 6.0.0 
Node       : v6.9.5
npm        : 5.4.0 
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

Tested with xcode simulator iPhone 6 Plus

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`.scroll-content {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto !important;
  }`

add it in the scss file.

Comment: -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; touch doesnt work, auto works as expected. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer from Leonardo Pineda is right , But It's not good way to update directly into native file instead We should go for create custom plugin which will disable bouncing on iOS.

Step 1. Clone the plugin from github repo (https://github.com/dtrmangesh/plugin-disable-ios-bouncing).

Step 2. Add repository path into your `package.json`

```
"dependencies": { BouncingIos : "git+<https://github.com/dtrmangesh/plugin-disable-ios-bouncing>"}
```

Comment: Do we need to import this after adding the dependency?

Comment: No need to add any dependency , please try with these steps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm upgrading from Ionic 3 to Ionic 5 and found this post. But then just found the solution in documentation.
I'm using Ionic 5 (not sure if Ionic 4 works too). Just add `slot="fixed"` to element inside `ion-conent`:

```html
<ion-content
  [scrollEvents]="true"
  (ionScrollStart)="logScrollStart()"
  (ionScroll)="logScrolling($event)"
  (ionScrollEnd)="logScrollEnd()">
    <h1>Main Content</h1>

    <div slot="fixed">
      <h1>Fixed Content</h1>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

It works perfect in iOS.
Source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content