# To disable bouncing effect in ios scroll ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

I tried some methods to disable bounce effect set no-bounce attribute to ion-content

```
<ion-content no-bounce></ion-content>
```

And added styles to ion-content to disable bounce. Still no fix to my problem.

Comment: Do you have any update about that problem? I'm in the same issue with no solution.

Comment: Till no solutions. Boucing is a part of the ios features. If we try to disable scrolling it will be choppy that is mentioned by ionic team..

Comment: Man, It works for me. I put no-bounce has-bouncing="false" and my ion-content and it worked.
My stupid error was testing only with cordova run ios --device, when I put ionic in front it generate again the project and it works like a charm now.

Comment: @FelipeFerreiradoAmaral post this as an answer, I followed your comment and it worked for me.

Comment: @FelipeFerreiradoAmaral sir i have faced same issue bouncing-effect as well scrolling is not working in the iphone7 device as well as screen freezed but in the another iphone list is scrolled do you have any idea sir why list is not scrolled in the iphone7 only?

Comment: @Kapilsoni Sorry for that but I don't have an Iphone 7 here for test and unfortunately I can't provide any additional idea about it.

Comment: @FelipeFerreiradoAmaral: its ok sir actually i stuck this issue last 4 days?

Comment: Please check this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555096/disable-content-bouncing-scroll/60467837#60467837> , It should solve your issue

Answer (score 10):

It works on Ionic 4 with this. (Sorry, I don't have an explanation).

```
<ion-content no-bounce has-bouncing="false" forceOverscroll="false">
```

Comment: I believe in Ionic 4+ `forceOverscroll="false"` is enough

Answer (score 3):

After couple of hours, I have find an answer from Github issues and I would like to share the solution, which then will disable the bounce effect in the iOS device.

Steps:

> 1. Run command, `ionic cordova platform add ios && ionic cordova prepare ios`
> 2. Then find `CDVWKWebViewEngine.m`, inside `/platforms/ios/<ionic-project>/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/`
> 3. Put this line of code at the bottom of the lines and save it.

```
@implementation UIScrollView (NoBounce)
- (void)didMoveToWindow {
   [super didMoveToWindow];
   self.bounces = NO;
}
@end
```

Credit link: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/113

Tested on Ionic 4, working on iOS device

Comment: thanks a lot snow i have finally fixed above issue thanks fir above solution

Comment: How to do this on capacitor?

Answer (score 2):

## Version: Ionic 5+

There seem to be various ways:

#### Disable bounce & disable vertical scroll:

```html
<ion-content scrollY="false">
```

Problems This also **disables scroll in general**, which is what one might now want.

#### Disable bounce without disabling scroll:

```html
<ion-content forceOverscroll="false">
```

This works in my case perfectly, even though [the documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#properties) is a bit confusing about this flag.

Comment: This seems to work on pages where content is shorter than viewport. If content is larger than viewport, bounce still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

For ionic 4

```
<ion-content forceOverscroll="false">
```

Just using forceOverscroll="false" worked for me, the docs say do the opposite

Answer (score 0):

The only solution which worked with **IONIC - V5** is this plugin:
https://github.com/mangeshdatar/plugin-disable-ios-bouncing

- Install the plugin using npm by `npm i disable-ios-scrolling`.
- Add `disable-ios-scrolling` into your plugin section in package.json

As mentioned in the official document `forceOverscroll` property only works when the page content is shorter than the viewport.

```
<IonContent forceOverscroll={false}></IonContent>
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved my problem with this:

```
<ion-content scrollY="false">
```