# Disable ion-content top and bottom bounce

Tags: ionic-framework

How do I disable top and bottom bounce in `ion-content`?  I've tried adding overflow-scroll and no such luck:

```
<ion-content [scrollY]="!disableScroll" overflow-scroll="false">
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Please refer to this link, varified on V5 [IOS bouncing effect fix for IONIC-V5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72433926/1317637)

Answer (score 1):

Use **forceOverscroll** for that

```
<ion-content forceOverscroll="false">

</ion-content>
```

Comment: In Capacitor 6 using Angular you’ll need to write the attribute is as an expression

`<ion-content [forceOverscroll]="false">`

Answer (score 0):

Please add below line in config.xml :

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
```

And run below command :

```
ionic cordova prepare ios
```

Re-run the app , i hope app will working fine.