# Remove iOS scroll bounce in ionic 3

Tags: ios, typescript, scroll, ionic3

I’m developing an `Hybrid` app for both iOS and Android using `ionic-3`.

On Android, when the user reaches the bottom of the page, the scrolling stops. On iOS, when the user reaches the bottom of the page it “bounces” past the end of the page and shows a white background. I don’t want it to do this - the background of my page is dark grey, and this overscroll looks terrible.

I’ve already added the following three lines to the config.xml file:

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

But they don’t have any effect.

What else can I do to prevent this over-scroll, bounce effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got solution.

> Method 1

I need to add 3 attribute to my `ion-content` tag

- no-bounce
- List item
- forceOverscroll="false"

Add as like below.

```
<ion-content no-bounce has-bouncing="false" forceOverscroll="false"></ion-content>
```

> Method 2

```
Simply run npm i ionic-angular@3.9.4-201903121725 in your project's directory :)
```

Comment: doesn't work for me in iOS device. The screen keep bouncing

Comment: I have found a working solution and post it here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46300066/to-disable-bouncing-effect-in-ios-scroll-ionic-3/59665069#59665069